# Compiler Optimization flags for ffmpeg on Intel Xeon Phi

Tags: ffmpeg, xeon-phi

I am trying to compile ffmpeg on Xeon Phi processor. Are there any specific compiler optimization flags specific for Xeon Phi that I can enable while configuring ffmpeg so that I can achieve better performance in terms of encoder frames per second?

Encoder used: x264
Operating System: CentOS 7.2
Compiler: GCC 4.8.5

Currently, I am configuring ffmpeg with the below command line:

```
./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" 
--extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" 
--extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" --bindir="$HOME/bin" 
--pkg-config-flags="--static" --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree 
--enable-libx264
```